# How to import a CSV to postgresql that already has ID's assigned?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 3 CSV files that are about 150k rows each. They already have been given ID's in the CSV and the assosciations are held within them already. Is there a simple way to skip the auto-assignment of the id value and instead use what is already in the CSV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column only draws the next number from a sequence **by default**. If you write a value to it, the default will not kick in. You can just `COPY` to the table ([see @Saravanan' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794365/939860)) and then update the sequence accordingly. *One* way to do this:

```
SELECT setval('tbl_tbl_id_seq', max(tbl_id)) FROM tbl;
```

`tbl_id` being the serial column of table `tbl`, drawing from the sequence `tbl_tbl_id_seq` (default name).

Best in a *single transaction* in case of concurrent load.

Note, there is no off-by-1 error here. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html)

> The two-parameter form sets the sequence's last_value field to the
>   specified value and sets its `is_called` field to true, meaning that the
>   **next `nextval` will advance the sequence** before returning a value.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. Except, note that in my case, sequence id columns in my tables are simply named `id`, so the command I ended up using successfully was `SELECT setval('tbl_id_seq', max(id)) FROM tbl;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly copy the CSV records to POSTGRES table.

```
COPY table_name FROM '/path/to/csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

By following the above method, we can actually avoid create a record through ActiveRecord object.

Comment: What about the sequence that supplies values for the `id` column?

Comment: @mu That has to be reset to the value accordingly isn't?

Comment: I'm pretty sure COPY won't do it for you so that COPY will leave you with a busted table (i.e. future INSERTs are likely to fail due to duplicate PKs) unless you do a [`setval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) to fix the sequence.

Comment: PS: You can do this through the underlying PostgreSQL driver that Rails will be using: [`copy_data`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:copy_data)