# Manually update the counter used for generation of primary key in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, postgresql

In my spring project, the tables in database are created automatically by Hibernate using my entity classes as base, but I insert some default values in the table manually (using pgAdmin3).

Because that, I am facing now this problem: when I try insert a value via Java code in one of the tables which already have values, I receive a error message, saying the primary key already exists in the database.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

That's how I declare my primary key in my class:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: What kind of column are you using for your primary keys?

Comment: I update my question to show how I declare my primary key

Answer (score 3):

Call this SQL query once per table to set the sequence to the next free number:

```
SELECT setval('tblname_id_seq', max(id)) FROM tblname;
```

`tblname` being the actual name of the table.

Hibernate may use a different naming convention, or the sequence may have been renamed. If you can't find the sequence behind the [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column, check with ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)):

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence(tblname, column_name)
```

More details:
[Modify Django AutoField start value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504513/modify-django-autofield-start-value/7655273#7655273)
[How to import a CSV to postgresql that already has ID's assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793903/how-to-import-a-csv-to-postgresql-that-already-has-ids-assigned/22795038#22795038)

Comment: What I understand here it's your example works to update this tblname_id_seq in the postgresql server. But I don't have this sequence, my primary keys are handled only by Hibernate.

Comment: @KleberMota: Serial numbers are typically handled by the RDBMS. There is a sequence object behind each `serial` column. Follow the links to the manual for more. I added a method to find the sequence.

Comment: hibernate_sequence is name of the sequence that hibernate uses by default. Try o look for this sequence in in pgAdmin3 use it in the query above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be that you declare the id as a primitive instead of a wrapper.

So instead of:

```
private int id;
```

You should have:

```
private Integer id;
```

When you create the entity with the id is initialized as 0, instead of NULL.

That's why you get duplicate id constraint violation exceptions.

Only when the id is NULL the AUTO generation strategy will delegate the id assignment to the database.

Comment: I update my code to change my Id as Integer, but still have the same problem (by the way, the entity isn't being initialized with 0, but with the last number in a sequence of numbers - in the moment the last number is 9 - , which match the number of elements I insert through the program, beacause that I think the Hibernate had your own counter).

Comment: [According to Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-pojo-identifier): "We recommend that you declare consistently-named identifier properties on persistent classes and that you use a nullable (i.e., non-primitive) type."

Comment: As for the default values being manually inserted, make sure you always use the sequence when inserting those and never assign values manually. Better to have your PRIMARY KEY set as: id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_table_sequence'::regclass)