# Use DEFAULT or INTEGER value as a SQL function's argument

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, concurrency, sql-insert

I am making a SQL function to perform a smart insertion and manage a many to many table (a trigger wouldn't work as one value is variable).

Here is a minimum set for the example:

```
link_foo_to_bar (foo_id int, bar_id int)
foo (id serial, name character varying)
```

And here's my sql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION smart_insert (bar_id integer, foo_id integer, name character varying name)
RETURNS void AS $body$
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (foo_id, name);
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar (CURRVAL('foo_id_seq'), bar_id);
$body$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Now the problem is that `foo_id` is a `serial` so either it gets `DEFAULT` or an `INTEGER` as an incoming value. The function doesn't accept the `DEFAULT` keyword. How should I change the function to allow this varying argument? Using a text type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you specify `DEFAULT` function arguments in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION smart_insert (
  name character varying,
  bar_id integer, 
  foo_id integer = -1
)
RETURNS void AS $body$
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (
  CASE foo_id WHEN -1 THEN NEXTVAL('foo_id_seq') ELSE foo_id END, 
  name
);
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar (
  CASE foo_id WHEN -1 THEN CURRVAL('foo_id_seq') ELSE foo_id END,
  bar_id
);
$body$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Here's how you can call it:

```
-- with an explicit foo_id:
smart_insert('abc', 1, 2);

-- applying the default value:
smart_insert('abc', 1);
```

... however, there's some [useful feedback from Erwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159071/521799) that you should consider regarding inserting into `serial` types, which you should be careful with.

Comment: thanks, i still didn't try but if foo_id is the last parameter of my function, do i still need to specify the arguments' name in the function's call ?

Comment: @발렌텐: In fact, defaulted arguments must all be at the end anyway. I've fixed the answer accordingly. No, you don't have to specify the argument names, then.

Comment: wait.. the CURRVAL function is no use if NEXTVAL is not called right ? I should apply a CASE statement on the second insert as well, shouldn't I ?

Comment: @발렌텐: Yes, I'm sorry. I overlooked this. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, always provide **explicit target columns** for persisted `INSERT` statements. If you put that in a function and later change columns of the table, your function will either break, or ***worse*** not break and do unintended things.

Next, you **should not enter values into a `serial`** column to begin with. That leads to key collisions. You would need to get the underlying `SEQUENCE` back in sync with the currently highest value in the `serial` column, which can be tricky with concurrent write load. Just don't do it.

- [Manually update the counter used for generation of primary key in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818345/manually-update-the-counter-used-for-generation-of-primary-key-in-hibernate/23818603#23818603)

I suspect you really have a case of **`SELECT`-or-`INSERT`**. Meaning, if the given `name` already exists in `foo`, `SELECT` its associated `foo_id`, else `INSERT` a new row and use the dynamically assigned new `foo_id`.

The question does not seem to concern default values for function parameters so much as the keyword `DEFAULT` in SQL `INSERT` statements (completely different thing!) While you *can* use a function, you don't *need* a function for this.

### Without concurrent write load

You could use a data-modifying CTE (with or without function):

```
WITH val(name, bar_id) AS (SELECT 'given_name'::varchar, 7)
     -- type cast needed for varchar, but numeric constant typed automatically
   , sel AS (SELECT f.foo_id, v.bar_id FROM foo f JOIN val v USING (name)
   , ins AS (INSERT INTO foo(name)
             SELECT name FROM val
             WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)  -- only if not found
             RETURNING foo_id)
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
SELECT foo_id, bar_id FROM sel
UNION  ALL
SELECT foo_id, bar_id FROM ins, val;
```

More details:

- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT...RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)

Or if you really must sometimes force a manual `foo_id` ...
This variant wrapped into an SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION smart_insert(
   _name   varchar
 , _bar_id integer
 , _foo_id integer = NULL)  -- no default necessary, but NULL for convenience
RETURNS void AS
$func$
WITH sel AS (SELECT f.foo_id  -- existing foo_id overrules
             FROM   foo f WHERE f.name = _name)
   , ins AS (INSERT INTO foo(foo_id, name)
             SELECT COALESCE(_foo_id, nextval('foo_id_seq')), _name
             WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)  -- only if not found
             RETURNING foo_id)
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
SELECT foo_id, _bar_id FROM sel
UNION  ALL
SELECT foo_id, _bar_id FROM ins;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call ... [like Lukas instructed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30156045/939860)

Key element is `COALESCE(_foo_id, nextval('foo_id_seq')`: if you pass `_foo_id` it gets used, else the default is drawn from the sequence. Whatever you pick, it's returned with `RETURNING foo_id` and inserted down the line.

### With concurrent write load

#### Postgres 9.4

You could use the function from this related answer that deals with the concurrency problem (and provides more explanation):

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

```
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
VALUES (f_foo_id('given_name'), 7);
```

#### Postgres 9.5

Still in development, but a couple of days ago the new [`UPSERT` feature has been committed](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=168d5805e4c08bed7b95d351bf097cff7c07dd65) (yay!) and will be in the next release. But don't hold your breath, release is scheduled towards the end of 2015.

```
WITH val(name, bar_id) AS (SELECT 'given_name'::varchar, 7)
     -- type cast needed for varchar, but numeric constant typed automatically
   , ins AS (INSERT INTO foo(name)
             SELECT name FROM val
             ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING  -- conflicting row is locked
             RETURNING foo_id)
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
SELECT foo_id, bar_id FROM ins, val;
UNION  ALL
SELECT f.foo_id, v.bar_id FROM foo f JOIN val v USING (name)
LIMIT  1;
```

Details in the devel manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-insert.html

Aside: a trigger would almost certainly be possible, too. Not necessarily the better choice, though.

Comment: Looking forward to `UPSERT`, too! Thanks for the documentation link, that'll be very useful